# Why is this For loop running twice?

Tags: file, batch-file

I don't know Windows command interpreter well, but I have a VBA macro in a Microsoft Access file that runs the batch file as posted below.

Why is it putting 6 pipes at the end of the file and not three?

I believe that it's running twice but I don't know why.

```
@echo off
:: Copy inventory files from P drive and remove originals

move P:\MFG_Programs\MakenaInventory\THERACOM_TherRxHub_ControlFile_SP002B_*.txt N:\pgh_manufacturer_program_reporting\Makena\Process

:: create temp file mirroring inventory file with extra pipe on each line
p:
cd "P:\MFG_Programs\MakenaInventory"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For %%J in (RtlInventory_TherRxHub_SP002B*.txt) Do (
    For /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%%J) Do (
        echo %%A^|^|^|>>rtltemp.txt
    )
```

Comment: Your question states that it's putting six pipes at the end of each file, but the code suggests that you are appending to each line. Which of the two is your intention?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you've oversimplified the code.

change

```
For %%J in (RtlInventory_TherRxHub_SP002B*.txt) Do (
```

to

```
For /f "delims=" %%J in ('dir /b /a-d RtlInventory_TherRxHub_SP002B*.txt') Do (
```

This builds a `dir` list in basic form without directorynames in memory and then processes the list so that if you make filestructure changes by creating, deleting or renaming files within the directory, those changes do not affect the list already built.

Comment: Thanks I will try what you suggested.

Comment: I just tried it now instead of putting six pipes |||||| at the end of the file it isn't adding any pipes to the end of the line.  Sorry, I don't know DOS, I'm am a Microsoft Access Programmer and I took over a system that uses DOS Batch files to transmit data.  Please help.

Comment: Here is the code again.  It is mean to add three pipes to the end of a file to match the code that the user needs:

Comment: cd "P:\MFG_Programs\MakenaInventory" Setlocat enabledelayedexpansion For %%J in (RtlInventory_TherRxHub_SP002B*.txt) Do ( For /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%%J) Do (echo %%A^|^|^|>>rtltemp.txt)

Comment: On my test system, both your original and the modification I made cause the output file to be the combination of the contents of each file matching the RtlIn...02B*.txt filemask; each line with 3 pipes appended, which is exactly what I expect from the code. The modification I suggested was on the assumption that you had omitted a file-rename which can cause `for %%x in (filemask)..` to act unexpectedly. I'm confused by your actual requirements. Where should the three pipes appear? Could you edit some sample lines from ...sp002b?.txt into your question?

Comment: Here is the input file:  03/13/17|2017-03|SP002B|64011024301|MAKENA|03/06/17|8|12/17|52 and I would like to add three pipes to the end so it will match the user's file 03/13/17|2017-03|SP002B|64011024301|MAKENA|03/06/17|8|12/17/52|||

Comment: This is what it's doing now:  03/13/17/2017-03|SP002B|64011024301|MAKENA|03/06/17|8|12/17/52||||||

Comment: It works quite happily for me *however* the line you've provided contains non-ASCII characters X'E2808CE2808B` between the `17|` and the `52` which *may* have something to do with the problem.